# ColdFusion Builder 2018 Demo - Keyboard Shortcuts Issue on Windows 7 Pro

Tags: coldfusion, keyboard-shortcuts, coldfusionbuilder

I am running a demo version of ColdFusion Builder 2018, but I can't get the keyboard shortcuts to work. As per the instructions...to "Wrap In CF Comment":

> I Press Control+T,  Release,  Then Press M.
> I also tried. Press Control+T,  Don't Release Either Key,  Press M.
> I also tried. Press Control+T,  Release Just T,  Press M.
> I also repeated all the above after drinking 2 shots of Scotch.

In every case the Keyboard Shortcut Window pops-up showing the list of options with key combinations...but the actual key sequence doesn't work.  To apply the option I must Select it from the list...then Hit Enter to apply.

This can't be right.
Is there anything about Windows 7 Pro and ColdFusion Builder that may be causing this?
Additional settings in ColdFusion Builder?
Any recommendations?  Thanks.

Comment: Do any shortcuts work?  For example, does ctrl-s save your file?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the first problem might be that Windows 7 isn't officially supported for CF Builder 2018. Are you running at least the recommended version of Eclipse and the JRE?

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/user-guide.html/coldfusion/builder/system-requirements.ug.html

Windows

- Windows 2016 Server, Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012.
- 2 GHz or faster processor, 2 GB of RAM (4 GB recommended), 3 GB of available hard-disk space (additional space is needed for projects), DVD-ROM drive
- Java™ Virtual Machine: Oracle® JRE 10
- Eclipse 4.7.2 or higher for plug-in installation